# How to create sub-vectors out of a vector? Each sub-vector is made of the succeeding values from the main vector

Tags: r

I am trying to create sub-vectors from the main vector. Each sub-vector will comprise of the next succeeding value in the main vector.

I am trying to avoid loops. `x` is the input and I want the output as `vec_1`, `vec_2` and so on.

```
x<-c(23,45,32,45,1,67,89,92,101,5,63,42,65)

vec_1 <- c(23,45)

vec_2 <- c(23,45,32)

vec_3 <- c(23,45,32,45)

vec_4 <- c(23,45,32,45,1)
```

I tried to generate a vector of strings with the indexes in this way.
I am unable to convert the strings from say, `"1:5"` to `c(1:5)`.

```
x<-c(23,45,32,45,1,67,89,92,101,5,63,42,65)

a<-paste("1:",c(5:length(x)),sep="")

x[as.integer(a[1])] ###This does not work
```

Comment: Why do you want to avoid doing a loop ?

Comment: IMHO a for-loop is sufficient. Make a list upfront and fill in every subsequent subvector as new list element. Or use `lapply` as @RonakShah promotes. Just that you know: `lapply` is in fact a loop as well..

Comment: The data on which I want to run this is huge and running loops in R will obviously make it slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `lapply` and subset the values of `x` to create a list of vectors.

```
lapply(seq_along(x), function(p) x[seq_len(p)])

#[[1]]
#[1] 23

#[[2]]
#[1] 23 45

#[[3]]
#[1] 23 45 32

#[[4]]
#[1] 23 45 32 45

#[[5]]
#[1] 23 45 32 45  1
#....
```

If you want to name them you can do

```
a1 <- lapply(seq_along(x), function(p) x[seq_len(p)])
a1 <- setNames(a1, paste0("vec", seq_len(length(x))))
```

and can access each one individually by using its names.

```
a1[["vec1"]]
#[1] 23
a1[["vec2"]]
#[1] 23 45
```

---

You can do the same with `map` as well

```
purrr::map(seq_along(x), function(p) x[seq_len(p)])
```

Answer (score 4):

An option using `split`

```
idx <- sequence(2:length(x))
split(x[idx], cumsum(idx == 1))
#$`1`
#[1] 23 45

#$`2`
#[1] 23 45 32

#$`3`
#[1] 23 45 32 45

#$`4`
#[1] 23 45 32 45  1

#$`5`
#[1] 23 45 32 45  1 67

# ...
```